# PostgresSqlException with activiti source code

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, intellij-idea, activiti

I have downloaded the latest source code of activity. I have changed the db.properties file as follows :

```
db=postgres
jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/WorkflowEngine
jdbc.username=postgres
jdbc.password=password
```

I have added the postgres dependency also. While I'm trying to deploy through 'intellij idea' it is working fine by pointing to the correct database,with the same code, I have created a war file and tried to deploy through tomcat directly by placing the war inside webapps.
Here I'm getting the exception like :

```
caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: couldn't check if tables are already present using metadata: connection refused. check that the hostname and port are  correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: connection refused. check that the hostname and port are  correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this error.

**UPDATE**

I have given a new database name and tried to start. Activiti is able to create 25 tables in the new database, but still gives the connection refused error.

[image]

Comment: To be sure: all IntelliJ, Postgres **and** Tomcat are running on the same machine?

Comment: yes,all are running on same machine

Comment: What about the db.properties file - is it in a place where tomcat can load it?

Comment: activiti-explorer.war file is having the db.properties file.Inside tomcat webapps-> activiti-explorer -> db.properties is exist.(db.properties is having the same properties which i have added)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is pretty clearly a jdbc connection refused error.  So let's start with a checklist for troubleshooting these.

1. Can you psql into the server on a local socket?  just type psql from the command line.  If you get an authentication error or a password prompt you are good.  If you get a connection refused you have more work to do.
2. Is PostgreSQL running?  If not, start it and try again.  If so, check the postgresql.conf to look for non-standard port settings.
3. Check firewalls that might be preventing network connections.

Comment: 1. Getting the pwd prompt
2. PG is running, able to connect in pgadmin on localhost:5432
3. Firewall is off 

If I run from Intellij IDEA directly, the application running without any issues. When I deploy a war file to tomcat(created using maven), I am getting the error.

Comment: then the next step might be to log in Tomcat where it is trying to connect and trace your code that way.

Comment: Just one more info, if i give a wrong database name in conf file, i am getting 'invalid database' error. But if I give the correct databse, it am getting connection refused. Also, since it is working from intellij, I am not able to actually debug the application using the IDE.